# How to get only question title and accepted answer with specific tags via the API?

Tags: support, api

How can I get questions with x, y, z tags having at least three upvotes and with an accepted answer?

Also, I would like to only retrieve the question title, only the accepted answer, tags on questions and authors of the question and answers using Stack Exchange API.

Comment: Something like [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=asc&min=3&sort=votes&accepted=True&tagged=javascript%3Bstring%3Bdate&site=stackoverflow&filter=!0W6RWJmA8J-4NrSS.kwEMzHU5)? You can't shape the results from the API as easy as you could with a sql statement. Do post processing in your favorite tool stack.

Comment: @rene I am able to use those api end points, check my answer, I was wondering for something like that but not restricted to a particular account. Thank you for your effort on putting a comment on my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer or acceptable for this question,  but still it should give a better idea.

I think it is only possible if you have the data. It comes under private data.

The steps will be

1. Register an application
2. Get a code, using private_info scope
3. Get an accessToken
4. Create a filter
5. The request URL will be something like

   ```
    https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=1&fromdate=1579564800&todate=1582243200&order=desc&min=1579564800&max=1582243200&sort=activity&tagged=[stretching]or[flexibility]or[warm-up]or[martial-arts]or[flexibility]&site=fitness&filter=filterToken&access_token=accessToken&key=key
   ```

It can not be used to get others' questions and answers.